# Label points on a map with one function call

Tags: graphics, map, geography

I want to place labels on a geographic map. I can do this with individual points as in the code below

```
Show[
  CountryData["France", {"Shape", "Mercator"}], 
  Frame -> True, 
  Epilog -> 
    {PointSize[0.01], Red, Point[mercPoints], 
     Text[Abbeville, {3, 47}, 
       BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 12}], 
     Text[Agen, {3, 50}]}]
```

But this is not my aim. I have a list containing the names I want to label the points with (say `stationNames`). How do I attach each of the label names in `stationNames` to its respective point given by `mercPoints`, which is the list giving the longitude and latitude of each point.

Comment: You might try some like `MapThread[Text[#1, #2], {names, mercPoints}]`

Comment: Hi, your line of code returned an error when I tried it.   'An unknown box name (Text[#, #2]) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression'

Comment: Sorry. Left out &. Try `MapThread[Text[#1, #2]&, {names, mercPoints}]`